# Warning: failed to read path from javaldx terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::DeploymentException'

Tags: python, java, subprocess, cloud-foundry, libreoffice

I have a dash app on Cloud Foundry calling headless libreoffice like so:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env["HOME"] = os.getcwd()
env['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/bin/:/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/:$PATH'
env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/libreoffice/program/:/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/'
env['JAVA_HOME'] = '/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/'

command = ['soffice',
           '--headless',
           '--nodefault',
           '--nofirststartwizard',
           '--convert-to html',
           '--convert-images-to',
           "png" ,
           f"{filename}",
           '--outdir ',
           f"{output_path}"]
output = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, env=env)
```

My manifest file looks like this:

```
- name: a
  env:
    PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/bin/:/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/:$PATH
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/vcap/deps/0/lib/libreoffice/program/:/home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/
    JAVA-HOME: /home/vcap/deps/0/apt/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/
  memory: 5G
  health-check-type: process
  timeout: 300
  disk_quota: 8G
  instances: 1
```

My apt.yml:

```
packages:
- libxinerama1
- libreoffice
- libreoffice-java-common 
- default-jre
```

I get the error:

```
javaldx failed!\nWarning: failed to read path from javaldx\nterminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::DeploymentException
```

What could be the reason?